# How to implement Firebase pagination in a NextJS 13 server component?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-server-components

I'm currently trying to create a product page that displays all products and is a server component.
The problem that I've run into is that I can't find a way to pass the last visible document snapshot required by the startAfter() query.

This is the function I'm using to get the documents:

```
export async function getProducts() {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "products"),
    where("isHidden", "==", false),
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
    limit(12)
  );

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
  const products = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    products.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
  });
  return { products, lastDoc };
}
```

And this is the page itself:

```
export default async function ProductsBikiniPage({ searchParams }) {
  const page = searchParams["page"] ?? "1";

  const { products, lastDoc } = await getProducts();

  return (  
    <main>
      <section>
        //Listing products here
      </section>
      <section>
        <PaginationControls>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

The page params are there because at first I tried to paginate using pages but learned that firebase startAfter() needs a document snapshot to work (Can't just use .skip(12) for example).
So yeah, I can't figure out a way to pass this lastDoc back to the getProducts function to get the next set of products without changing the component to a client component.
Any ideas on how I can implement Firebase pagination in a Next server component would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`startAfter` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#startafter) actually has two overloads:

- One variant takes a `DocumentSnapshot` as its parameter, and will start after that document.
- The other variant takes a list of field values as its parameter, and is documented as:

> `fieldValues`
> `unknown[]`
> The field values to start this query after, in order of the query's order by.

So based on these overloads you can:

- either first load the document snapshot of the document to start after, for example based on its document ID - and then pass that snapshot to the first overload of `startAfter`.
- or you can pass along all the field values that are involved in the conditions and order of the query, and pass those along to the second overload of `startAfter`.

The second approach has the advantange that it doesn't require an extra document load, but the first variant actually is a bit simpler to implement.